# Finding the Right Files to Build Android Project in Classic Online Tutorial

Tags: java, android, xml, projects-and-solutions

I am having problems with Week 7 of this tutorial, https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193a/lectures.shtml. On Week 7, There is only the .java files showing which was problematic when I ran the build on Android studio.

Do I need an xml file or not? Why could they not have been shown as in the earlier weeks the xml files were shown as well.

I opened the zip file for the Targets app and found in Targets/app/src/main/res/layout the following xml file,

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TargetsActivity">

    <com.example.stepp.targets.TargetsView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but when I copy it into the project where I pasted the .java files, ExampleView.java and TargetsView.java,

```
 /*
 * CS 193A, Winter 2015, Marty Stepp
 * This class is a graphical view of a basic example of 2D graphics.
 */

package com.example.stepp.targets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class ExampleView extends View {
    public ExampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /*
     * This method draws some shapes and text on the view.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 90, 90);

        Paint aqua = new Paint();
        aqua.setARGB(255, 0, 80, 220);

        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(10, 30, 300, 700), aqua);
        canvas.drawOval(new RectF(400, 50, getWidth(), getHeight()), aqua);

        Paint font = new Paint();
        font.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
        font.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC));
        font.setTextSize(40);

        canvas.drawText("CS 193A is great", 80, 200, font);
    }
}
```

and

```
    /*
 * CS 193A, Winter 2015, Marty Stepp
 * This class is a graphical view of a drawing of a red/white target figure.
 */

package com.example.stepp.targets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class TargetsView extends View {
    public TargetsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /*
     * This method draws the target oval shapes on the view.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint red = new Paint();
        red.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);

        Paint white = new Paint();
        white.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            canvas.drawOval(new RectF(w*i/10, h*i/10, w*(10-i)/10, h*(10-i)/10), (i % 2 == 0 ? red : white));
        }
    }
}
```

I dont see why this doesnt work because the same method working in the early weeks. Help is much appreciated. Nor can I see why there is a need for two different activities ExampleView and TargetsView.

I am having the same problem in the other latter weeks of this tutorial as I cannot see where to find the correct java and xml files.

This problems forms what seems to be a common error for those following this prominent tutorials on android app development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the whole Targets.zip.

The two classes you included in the question are class `extends View`. They are just UI components that will not make anything happen by themselves.

These two classes can be included into a layout xml or used (constructed programmatically) by Activity class. As you can see in the layout xml you found, it includes a tag called `<com.example.stepp.targets.TargetsView ... />`, which means this layout will have a TargetView inside.

An Activity class is actually the one who coordinating UI components and logics. In your Targets.zip, you have a `TargetsActivity.java` as well, which is a Acitivity class. It tries to fetch `R.layout.activity_targets` and set it as content view by calling `setContentView(...)` in the `onCreate()` method.

Finally you have `AndroidManifest.xml` at src/main. You can see in the `<activity ...> ... </activity>` node, TargetsActivity is specified as the launcher activity, which means when the app starts, this Acitivity class will be the first activity to start.